# Why am I receiving an error for return_train_score when trying to cross validate

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to execute a for loop for the following dictionary, but I am receiving an error that states:

"cross_val_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_train_score'"

I thought this was a valid parameter for cross_val_score so I'm a bit confused any help would be appreciated,

thanks

```
results_dict = {
    "n_neighbors": [],
    "mean_train_score": [],
    "mean_cv_score": []}

results_dict

for k in range(2,20, 2):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    scores = cross_val_score(knn, X_train, y_train, cv=5, return_train_score=True)
    results_dict['n_neighbors'].append(k)
    results_dict['mean_train_score'].append(['train_score'])
    results_dict['mean_cv_score'].append(['test_score'])

results_dict
```

Comment: `return_train_score` is a parameter to `cross_validate()`, not `cross_val_score()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Check documentation of the cross_val_score function here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)

The cross_val_score doesn't have any such parameter named return_train_score. So, I suggest removing this parameter will eliminate this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the function `cross_validate` instead of `cross_val_score`.